# Pass a Team City Parameter to a PowerShell file

Tags: powershell, teamcity, powershell-2.0, teamcity-9.0

I have the following parameter defined in Team City:

[image: Team City Parameter]

I want to pass this parameter into a powershell script I have (that will update the xml file with the version number).

[image: Step With Parameter as Argument]

But this inserts the actual text `%version%` into the script (No substitution is made for the actual value of the parameter.)

However, I know my script is working because if I hardcode the values like this then it works:

[image: Step with hard coded parameter]

**Is there a way to get %version% to convert to the actual value when when used as a PowerShell script argument?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the parameter in quotes, "%version%", and change the script execution mode to Execute ps1 script with "-File" argument then this should resolve and inject correctly

e.g.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't see the option to execute with the -File option in version 9.  And I just upgraded to version 10 and it is not there either.  I am guessing this is an option for older versions?

Comment: Putting it in quotes was the solution.  Once I did that it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need Environment Variables (env.), it's work to me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2cjj.png)

Comment: Your example demonstrates adding environment variables to scripts which are written in the Team City UI, not source control as was specified in the original question. Your answer is not relevant to this situation.